# How do multi-constraint generic function calls actually work?

Tags: .net, vb.net

In vb.net, it is possible to design a function which can operate on generic parameters which meet multiple constraints.  For example, it is possible to have a function accept as a parameter a class which inherits from Control and implements IList.  This function could use "Control" or "IList" methods on such an object, and also pass the object to anything that expected a Control or an IList [note that this particular combination was chosen to facilitate a brief example, not to be a particularly useful combination].

```
    Sub CrossThreadAdd(Of T, U As {Control, IList(Of T)})(ByVal TheControl As U, ByVal NewThing As T)
        If TheControl.InvokeRequired Then
            TheControl.BeginInvoke(New Action(Of U, T)(AddressOf CrossThreadAdd), TheControl, NewThing)
        Else
            TheControl.Add(NewThing)
        End If
    End Sub
```

This approach provides compile-time type-safety; there's no need for a cast that could fail at runtime.  An alternative approach would be to pass the argument as either a Control or an IList, and have the function cast to the other.  That would, however, fail at runtime if the object that was passed didn't in fact meet both constraints.

Under what circumstances is it good to use a generic function like the above, in what cases would it be better to have objects which are going to meet both constraints have a new interface like IListableControl(Of T) which would include a TheControl property that would return itself (cast as a control), and in what cases would it be better to have a generic ISelf(of T) interface, any implementor of which would be expected to provide a "Self" property that would return itself as a T?

Using multi-constrained generics, it's possible to do a lot of things without requiring any run-time typecasts, but I don't know what the performance costs are likely to be.  I tried writing a short program to generate 65,536 different generic types at run-time, e.g. Foo(of Bar(Of Foo(Of Foo(Of Bar(Of Foo(...(Of Blah))...)))), and it got pretty slow, so I can tell that the time required to handle generics isn't fixed, but I don't know what factors affect it.

Answer (score 1):

There should be next to *no* runtime overhead to generic functions over normal functions. Likewise, the number of constraints has absolutely no bearing at runtime – it’s checked by the *compiler*. Different things of course apply when you’re using reflection to access these functions.

As for your question when such constraints are useful …

Personally, I would say: often. An interface should only ever model *one* concern. Having aggregating interfaces (e.g. `IListableControl`) sounds rather like code smell to me (of course, this assumes that generics with multiple constraints exist, otherwise they might actually be necessary to provide type safety).

Comment: Is there any way, without using aggregating interfaces, to store an object instance in a field or collection such that it can later be passed to a multi-constraint generic function?  Also, I'm sure there has to be *SOME* overhead--even if generics have a class constraint, the generic function still knows what types were passed in, independent of the types of its parameters (so "U" might be "ListBox" while TheControl might be an instance of "FancyRainbowColoredListbox").

Comment: @supercat: yes of course, you just need to encapsulate the collection in a class which has the desired constraints (e.g. `Of T, U As {Control, IList(Of T)}`) and then use that type in the internal collection (e.g. `List(Of U)`). And why are you convinced that there is an overhead? All the type testing is strictly done at compile-time only! If the type cannot be determined at compile time, the code won’t even compile.

Comment: If all things in the collection will be of the same type, and the type is resolvable at compile time, there's no difficulty.  Suppose, however, that there are two or more classes that both inherit from Control and IList(Of T), but no common ancestor inherits IList(Of T).  Is there any way to declare such a collection so that the items therein can be passed to a dual-constraint method?

Comment: @supercat: Whenever you want to store different object types within one container generics won’t help you … you *always* need to use a common base class or interface.

Comment: Unfortunately, it would seem this can make it very difficult to store dual-constraint items in a collection.  If the objects were being passed to a non-generic routine, one could store them as the declared parameter type or, if the object will be passed to different routines needing different declared types, one could typecast before passing to each routine.  Unfortunately, this approach won't work for dual-constraint generics if there isn't a common base type that's applicable to the whole collection.